# Having some trouble setting up a jQuery .css function

Tags: jquery, css, vbulletin

I'm attempting to create a jQuery function that will automatically resize a particular image to it's parent's width. If it's relevant this is for vbulletin 4.2.0

Here's the relevant (simplified) code:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
        var newWidth = $('.floatcontainer.doc_header').css("width");
        $('.logo-image').css("width", newWidth);

        });
    </script>
</head>

<div class="floatcontainer.doc_header" style="width: 90%; height: 200px;">
    <img class=".logo-image" src="/img/headerimg.jpg"/> //the image is naturally 1092x200
</div>
```

SOLVED! I finally figured out where to go to edit the css for this picture, so I didn't need to do it with jQuery. Not exactly the solution I was looking for, but hey - who's complaining!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't add dots in the class names. Dots are used as css selectors for selecting elements with class. i.e if you have an element with class="some_name", then you can select that element via the css selector .some_name

Answer (score 3):

Missing proper **class selector**

```
 $('.floatcontainer doc_header')
                    ^--- Missing the class selector
```

supposed to be

```
 $('.floatcontainer.doc_header')  // Make sure there is no space
                   ^----
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tk5qG/1/)**

**UPDATE**

I see what the problem is

```
<img class=".logo-image"
```

Has a **class with a dot in it ..**

So the correct selector for that is

```
$('.\\.logo-image')
```

**AND NOT**

```
$('.logo-image')
```

That is the reason it was not finding the specific Image

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tk5qG/3/)**

If you want it to work with the selector you have specified then change your class in HTML 
to

`<img class="logo-image"`
           **^--- No dot Here** .. So selector is  `$('.logo-image')`

`<img class=".logo-image"`
          **^--- dot present** .. So selector is  `$('.\\.logo-image')`

Comment: wow! I can't believe I overlooked that. I will edit that and see if that was it!

Comment: well, that's one mistake out of the way, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: $('.floatcontainer.doc_header') <-- since both of the classes are set on the same element

Comment: Then Try this `.css("width", newWidth+ 'px');`

Comment: As @fredrik pointed it out the `class` corresponds to the same element so there should be no space between the selectors

Comment: @Sushanth-- I will try your suggestion now

Comment: Really... To my knowledge you cant have dots in class names. For example this answer stipulatrs that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: You can always have a . in the class name , but such characters have to be escaped with a `\\\`

Comment: @sushanth cool youre right but having dots in class names only bring confusion if you ask me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.logo-image').width($('.floatcontainer.doc_header').width());
```

Also you shouldnt be using dots in your element classes!

Possible also to change the css instead:

```
 .logo-image { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I tried this as well, and unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see my edit and removed the dots from your classes? (class=".logo-image" should be class="logo-image" etc)

Comment: The class name wasn't my choice, standard with vbulletin4.2 I tried both suggestions, but still no dice.